# NPM: package not found when installing a module that dependes on a tgz local package

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-install, package.json

I am trying to install an npm package `Module A` that has a dependency on a local .tgz package, called `Module B`.

For instance, the **package.json of** `Module A`, looks something like this:

```
{
  "name": "module-a",
  "dependencies": {
   "module-b": "file:./forked-packages/module-b.tgz",
  }
}
```

When trying to install `Module A` on a different project, I am getting the following error:

> npm WARN tarball tarball data for module-b@file:forked-packages/module-b.tgz (null) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.

And then it fails with a `ENOENT` code stating that the tgz path was not found.

The weird thing is that if I run `npm pack module-a`, and then check for the existance of `module-b`, the .tgz does exist in the correct path `forked-packages/module-b.tgz`

Any idea of what could be causing this error? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure that you are giving the correct path in the other project. Please share the folder structure of the other project and along with both module A and module B location.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that modules published to a registry must not have any local dependencies. From the docs:

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#local-paths

> This feature is helpful for local offline development and creating
> tests that require npm installing where you don't want to hit an
> external server, but should not be used when publishing packages to
> the public registry.
>
> note: Packages linked by local path will not have their own
> dependencies installed when npm install is ran in this case. You must
> run npm install from inside the local path itself.

I am trying to install `Module A` from a private registry, and this module has `Module B` as a local tgz dependency.